# Adding a drop-down selection to a multi-select column in Fusion Tables

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I've been using Fusion Tables for a while to do stuff but I'm a long way from being a javascript programmer so just need some help with getting some code working.

Basically, I've managed to build some maps with multiple layers on them and I've taught myself to add some filtering options below these (checkboxes and drop-downs).

What I'd really like to be able to do but cannot at the moment, however, is use a drop-down menu to query a column with multiple options.

In this example (with dummy data), I've produced a drop-down to select which of the markers on the map accept people of different ages...
http://owengriffiths.info/Drop-down.html

In order to do this, each row only had one option though (so they either had 'Under 16s', '16-17', '18-65' or 'Over 65s' selected). I want to have it so that a row might have entries such as 'Under 16s; 16-17; 18-65' in it and this would then make the marker stay on the map so long as 'Over 65s' wasn't selected.

I guess effectively what I want to do is for the drop down to query the column to see which rows *contain* that term rather than *equal* it.

Could anybody help...?

Comment: I've put it on jsfiddle too if that helps... http://jsfiddle.net/OwenG/9c5tU/

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you might want to take a look at Derek Eders Searchable Map Template: http://derekeder.com/searchable_map_template/

Comment: Hi Rod, Thanks for that - I've looked at Derek's template and, very impressive though it is, it's way beyond what I'm trying to achieve.